# Is it illegal to record someone located in a different state if you are in a one-party state?

Tags: united-states, wiretapping

If there is a telephone conversation between two people and one of the parties in is a one-party state A and the other is in a two-party state, B, is it illegal for the caller in state A to record the conversation? In other words, could a prosecutor in state B bring a successful criminal complaint against the caller in state A for recording a conversation without consent?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's illegal**

When party consent states differ, the state with the stricter laws apply.

Not only can criminal charges be brought against you, but there can also be a civil claims for damages.

[Recording Phone Calls and Conversations](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/recording-phone-calls-and-conversations)